# Google Chrome the fav-icon, not Shown using Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Guys currently I am facing one issue in my WordsPress website.

The issue is my web not showing the `favicon` in Google Chrome. And this `favicon` working properly in other browsers. This is my code sample Code. Can you help me please?

```
 <link rel="icon"  type="image/png"   href="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/melanie.png"/>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="wp-content/themes/success/images/fav/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="wp-content/themes/success/images/fav/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="wp-content/themes/success/images/fav/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="wp-content/themes/success/images/fav/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="wp-content/themes/success/images/fav/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="wp-content/themes/success/images/fav/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="wp-content/themes/success/images/fav/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="wp-content/themes/success/images/fav/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="wp-content/themes/success/images/fav/apple-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="wp-content/themes/success/images/fav/android-icon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="wp-content/themes/success/images/fav/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="wp-content/themes/success/images/fav/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="wp-content/themes/success/images/fav/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="wp-content/themes/success/images/fav/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="wp-content/themes/success/images/fav//ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Comment: Basic question but did you try shift+f5 to deep refresh the browser? Maybe it cached the HTML output, so you have to recache it. Or just try to visit it in incognito mode.

Comment: Yes, I'm also trying that but the issues are still there...

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code:

As a developer i use following fav link code for all website and it works fine.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/melanie.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/wp-content/themes/success/images/fav/apple-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/wp-content/themes/success/images/fav/apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/wp-content/themes/success/images/fav/apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/wp-content/themes/success/images/fav/apple-icon-152x152.png">
```

Remove the old code and replace with above one and give it a try.

Comment: I have updated the new code. Try to replace your code with above code and see the difference.